# Name of this recursively defined sequence of prime numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

I was wondering if the following sequence has a name:

Let $P$ be the set of prime numbers, and $p: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow P$ be the (increasing) enumerating function of the set.

Let's define $\alpha_1 = 2, \alpha_{n+1} = p(\alpha_n)$, i.e.,the $\alpha_n-$prime number.

Is there a name for this sequence? The first terms are $2,3,5,11,...$

I know they code one-branch-trees in [the Cappello (non standard) codification of rooted trees.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.90.6380&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (in fact that's why I'm interested in them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the sequence on [OEIS here](https://oeis.org/A007097) (A00707097). The name given is "Primeth recurrence".